# Por que se agrega un slash al final con url relativas

Tags: php, html

como puedo quitar el slash al final de la url, resulta ser que tengo mis enlaces de la siguiente forma

```
<a href="../contacto" class="nav-link">CONTACTO</a>
```

Pero al hacer clic en el enlace la ruta figura asi, con un slash al final

**http://localhost/ecuservicechile/contacto/**

Comment: Eso no es posible si `contacto` es un directorio. El servidor web hará una redirección automáticamente porque lo que quieres es ver el índice de un directorio (con la barra al final), y no el contenido de un archivo (sin la barra final). Puedes "trucar" el servidor web para que no haga dicha redirección, pero no te recomiendo complicarte la vida.

Comment: Es mejor que sea así, con `/` al final. Si por ejemplo te interesa computar el número de visitas a tus URLs con servicios como Google Analytics, estas dos URL son consideradas distintas: `...contacto/` y `...contacto`. Recuerdo que en mi sitio tuve que normalizar, forzando vía .htaccess a que todas las direcciones  terminen en `/` y que estén en minúscula. Porque me interesaba saber por medio de la API de Analytics las páginas más visitadas en un periodo de tiempo y guardar el total de visitas de cada página y cosas así.